# Gelfand-Leray integral for forms with noncompact support

Tags: analysis, reference-request, differential-geometry

Let $\omega$ be a smooth $n$-form with compact support on domain $\Omega \subseteq{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and let $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with nonvanishing differential. Then for any point $x \in \Omega$ there exists a neighborhood $U_\alpha$ in which we can take $f(x)$ as one of local coordinates and so there exists a smooth form $\psi_\alpha$ defined in this neighborhood with property $df \wedge \psi_\alpha = \omega$. Restriction of $\psi_\alpha$ on any level set $f(x)=t$ is unique. Let $U_{\alpha}$ be a finite cover of support of $\omega$ with such neighborhoods and $\chi_\alpha$ be the associated partition of unity. The form
$$
   \frac{\omega}{d f} = \sum_\alpha \chi_\alpha \psi_\alpha 
$$
is then the unique smooth form on each level set such that $df \wedge \frac{\omega}{df} = \omega$. This form is called Gelfand-Leray form and its integral
$$
    J(t) = \int\limits_{f(x)=t} \frac{\omega}{df}
$$
is called Gelfand-Leray function. It has the property that
$$
   \int\limits_\Omega \omega = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} J(t) \, dt. \tag{1}
$$
But is it possible to say something about existence of Gelfand-Leray form $\frac{\omega}{d f}$ in the case when $\omega$ is not compactly supported? Where can I read about this case?

Leaving aside question of existence let $\frac{\omega}{df}$ be such form. In which case the equalty (1) holds? In book [1] one says that to proove this we have to use the Fubini theorem.

*References*
[1] *V. I. Arnold, S. M. Gusein-Zade, A. N. Varchenko*, Singularities of Differentiable Maps, V.2, 1988